# Selecting unique display names from the following query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ ORDER BY displayname
```

The above query returen the row which contain repeated displayname (`columnname`)
how. Is there a way to get a resultset containg unique `displaynames`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct * FROM XYZ ORDER BY displayname
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM XYZ group by displayname ORDER BY displayname
```

Comment: `group by` comes before `order by`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `distinct`:

```
select distinct displayname from XYZ order by displayname
```

You can use `group by`:

```
select displayname from XYZ group by displayname order by displayname
```

If you use `distinct` you can only get the `displayname` field, unless you have another field which have the same value within each `displayname` value.

If you use `group by` you can use aggregates to get values from each group. You can for example return how many times each `displayname` occurs in the table:

```
select displayname, count(*) as cnt from XYZ group by displayname order by displayname
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT displayname FROM xyz ORDER BY displayname;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT * FROM XYZ ORDER BY displayname
    UNION 
  SELECT * FROM XYZ ORDER BY displayname
```

Comment: That's pointless. As the second query is identical to the first, only records from the first query will be in the result.

Comment: @Guffa - Strangely it probably would produce distinct results due to the `union` (after you remove the invalid `order by` clauses that is). Though I do not see a reason for doing this either, when it is much cleaner to use `distinct`.